# where is __proto__ for Number, Date, Boolean, Array

Tags: javascript

I draw a picture based on prototype chain relationship.

but wonder where the `__proto__` of Number, Date, Boolean, Array point to.

Your comment welcome

[image]

Comment: The `__proto__`  of Number, Boolean, Date, Array instances are of course their respective prototypes.

Comment: Of course the comments above are wrong and the answer is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, you can check the spec:

> [**15.7.3 Properties of the Number Constructor**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.3)
>
> The value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of the Number
>   constructor is the Function prototype object ([15.3.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4)).
>
> [**15.9.4 Properties of the Date Constructor**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4)
>
> The value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of the Date
>   constructor is the Function prototype object ([15.3.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4)).
>
> [**15.6.3 Properties of the Boolean Constructor**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.6.3)
>
> The value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of the Boolean
>   constructor is the Function prototype object ([15.3.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4)).
>
> [**15.4.3 Properties of the Array Constructor**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3)
>
> The value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of the Array
>   constructor is the Function prototype object ([15.3.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4)).

And the reasoning is that those objects are functions/constructors. So you may want to use function methods on them.

For example, a (bad) way to convert array-like objects to arrays:

```
Array.apply(void 0, {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', length: 3}) // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: This is interesting. typeof Array.apply(void 0, {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', length: 3}) -> 'object'. However typeof Array.apply(void 0, {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', length: 3}).forEach -> 'function'

Comment: @t3dodson Yes, arrays are objects, so `typeof [] === "object"`, and they inherit from `Array.prototype` which has a `forEach` method, so `typeof [].forEach === "function"`. The code in my answer returns an array, so the same applies.

Answer (score 2):

Since all of those are functions (`typeof Date` = `typeof Number` = `"function"`) it points to [`Function.prototype`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.3.1).

It's easy to verify by simply checking:

```
Date.__proto__ === Function.prototype; // true
```

This is the case because they *are* functions (you call them as functions), they contain all the things functions need to do (such as `.call` `.bind` and `.apply`)